# Accessing selected elements of a list of lists in R

Tags: r

I have a list of list `subgame[[i]]$Weight` of this type:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.4720550 0.4858826 0.4990469 0.5115899 0.5235512 0.5349672 0.5458720
[8] 0.5562970 0.5662715 0.5758226 0.5849754 0.5937532 0.6021778 0.6102692
[15] 0.6180462 0.6255260 0.6327250 0.6396582 0.6463397 0.6527826

[[2]]
[1] 0.4639948 0.4779027 0.4911519 0.5037834 0.5158356 0.5273443 0.5383429
[8] 0.5488623 0.5589313 0.5685767 0.5778233 0.5866943 0.5952111 0.6033936
[15] 0.6112605 0.6188291 0.6261153 0.6331344 0.6399002 0.6464260

[[3]]
[1] 0.4629488 0.4768668 0.4901266 0.5027692 0.5148329 0.5263534 0.5373639
[8] 0.5478953 0.5579764 0.5676339 0.5768926 0.5857755 0.5943041 0.6024984
[15] 0.6103768 0.6179568 0.6252543 0.6322844 0.6390611 0.6455976
```

What I am looking for is to access all the `j-th` elements of every list. Example if `j=1` I must get:

```
>0.4720550  0.4639948 0.4629488
```

How can I do it?
I found

```
sapply(1:length(subgame[[i]]$Weight),function(k) subgame[[i]]$Weight[[k]][1])
```

But seems too tricky to me.
There is a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3):

If `j=1`, then you're interested in `subgame[[i]]$Weight[[1]][1]`, `subgame[[i]]$Weight[[2]][1]`, and `subgame[[i]]$Weight[[3]][1]`. In other words, you want to use `[1]` on each list element.

But what happens when you subset a vector? For example:

```
(x <- rnorm(5))
# [1] -1.8965529  0.4688618  0.6588774  0.2749539  0.1829046
x[3]
# [1] 0.6588774
```

`[` is actually a function, and it gets called in this situation. You can read a bit more about it with `?"["`, but the point is that you can call it like any other function. Its first argument will be the object to subset, then you can pass it the index (or indices) you're interested in (along with some other arguments that the help page discusses):

```
x[3]
# [1] 0.6588774
`[`(x, 3)
# [1] 0.6588774
```

Note the backticks surrounding the name. A bare `[` will throw an error, so you need to quote it. The same goes for other functions like `+`.

So if you want to get the first element of each list element, you can apply `[` to each element of the list, passing it `1` or whatever `j` is:

```
sapply(subgame[[i]]$Weight, `[`, 1)
```

Comment: Can you explain better the meaning of `[` operator?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a solution which returns the result you want for the `Weight` list of each elements of your `subgame` list.

```
> subgame <- list(list(weight = list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4), c(5, 6))), list(weight = list(c(7, 8), c(9, 10), c(11, 12))))
> 
> j = 1
> 
> do.call(rbind, subgame[[1]]$weight)[,j]
[1] 1 3 5
>  
> lapply(subgame, function(x) {do.call(rbind, x$weight)[,j]})
[[1]]
[1] 1 3 5

[[2]]
[1]  7  9 11
```